# Why save uploaded image path in database?

Tags: php, database, image, path, upload

I have posts system where users can upload images inside a post, I intend to build the images paths url and not store the uploaded images paths in database.

I will simply use unique Post ID to build the url path for post images like:

```
$path = "images/{$postID}/";
```

Then when rendering the post I will use

```
$images = glob($path);
```

When post is deleted I will simply:

```
unlink($path);
```

Why all implementations for php image uploads that I read about contains table to store images paths? Why not this method are there any disadvantages that I am not aware about?

Comment: because if any time you want image than you fetch image using image path

Comment: @DeepBlue, everything has an advantage and a disadvantage, its upto you, how you use it

Answer (score 0):

I think that this one can go with a little discussion. Although the image location is recommended to be stored in the database, but it is **not always the best way**. If you according to your logic find some algorithm to uniquely name images based on blog id or something that would save you database latency cost.

For the same i would like to give example of a sample use case. You are either way fetching blog text from database. Now you can add another field to store the number of images that you have associated with the same. Now take the unique id of blog suppose `uq1`. If that blog has 6 images , you can name the images as

```
$path = $uq1.$imageindex
```

remember that you will also have to store the image in same path. You can always get fancy and add simple XOR encrypt. Although the use of XOR is mainly when you are also associating sensitive data to the same. This will save you some database latency.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

its a good idea doing it in this way.
unless you don't need duplicates of a lot of images
for example if you have image apple.jpg with size 500K, 
and you have 2000 posts that should have apple image in them.
so you will save 2000 x 500k of apple image.

but if you have it in the database and you just select images from
something as gallery so you will have only 1 image for apple.jpg
but it linked for 2000 posts using the database table.

but if you dont care! about duplicates and data size, or you are sure that there is no any post have any image like the other! so its ok.

**summary: saving all post images in folder with its id is the easy way
but it will cost you space ( duplicates and so on )
the other way, saving the image link in database and just link it with every post need it. its better.**

Comment: The images are uploaded by users so I dont know if there will be duplicate images! besides I should not care about comparing users images content which will add unneccessary complexity to the system. For example a user uploaded an image, it is not practical to compare image content with all images uploaded by other users.

Comment: hi, if you have an image gallery for every user so he can access images that he is uploading. so you every user will never have any duplicates.
but user1 and user2 may have duplicates. so you are decreasing it.
and NOO you will never ever compare uploaded images
but you have to give the user the ability to see what images he have.
as wordpress for example. you can add image from gallery or upload new one...